# Built-in Attributes for MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

Which attributes are supported for an ASP.NET MVC Controller?

E.g. `AuthorizeAttribute` and `OutputCacheAttribute` are only for Actions or can they be specified for Controllers as well?

Built-in attributes for ASP.NET MVC Controllers?

Comment: The experience doesn't necessarily have to be in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @J.Steen you are right. Maybe I'm have to much expectations from a MCP..

Comment: @CoffeeCode Possibly. =)

Answer (score 2):

There are 4 types of action filters

1. Authorization filters – Implements the `IAuthorizationFilter` interface.
2. Action filters – Implements the `IActionFilter` interface.
3. Result filters – Implements the `IResultFilter` interface.
4. Exception filters – Implements the `IExceptionFilter` interface.

Filters can be applied to a controller (in which case they would be executed for every method on the controller) or individual actions.

You can apply a mixture across controllers and actions depending on the scope of the code you want executed.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better if you take a look at this article:

- http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410209(v=vs.100).aspx

I find it more important not only to know the default action filters that are in ASP.NET MVC but more important is to know how to implement a your custom action filter that satisfies the application needs.